# Angular 2 property binding: how do EventEmitters work?

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding, properties

I've been working on learning Angular 2 two-way binding, and I've put together a demo that binds a component's property to another, contained component's property, as well as to several text fields. Unfortunately, a lot of it seems like [magic](http://www.outpost9.com/reference/jargon/jargon_46.html) to me, which makes it awfully hard to debug when the magic isn't working. In particular, the demo reveals several places where I don't yet fully understand binding; this question is the first of what may be several on this topic.

(The demo is at http://plnkr.co/edit/IUTy5p?p=preview, in case you want to follow along at home...)

The code implements a parent component with a `pName` string property, and a contained, child component with a `cName` property. The parent's property is two-way bound to the child's property using the banana box syntax:

```
<child [(cName)]="pName"></child>
```

Inside the child is a display of the `cName` property, as well as three text inputs, each of which is in some way bound to the `cName` property. The second text input is the important one here:

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="cName" (ngModelChange)="cNameChange.emit($event)">
```

The `ngModelChange` event invokes an `emit()` method on an `EventEmitter` whose name `cNameChange` is derived from the `cName` property's name:

```
@Output() public cNameChange:EventEmitter<String> = new EventEmitter<String>();
```

So, if you edit the second text input's value, the child's `cName` property changes, the other two text inputs change their values, and the parent's `pName` property changes.

But, **how**?

This can be split into two related questions:

1. How does emitting that event change the `cName` property?
2. How does changing the child's `cName` property end up changing the parent's `pName` property?

Answer (score 3):

The only real magic is the `[()]` syntax, which is specified by Angular. The rest can explained in the following sections

When we use `[(cData)]="pData"` it is the same as using

```
[cData]="pData" (cDataChange)="pData = $event"
```

where when an event is emitted to `cDataChange`, Angular guarantees to set the value of the bound input property (`[cData]="pData"`), in this case `pData` to the value emitted from the `cDataChange`

> 1. How does emitting that event change the `cName` property?

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <input type="text" [ngModel]="cName" (ngModelChange)="cNameChange.emit($event)">
  `
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() public cName:string = 'thisIsIgnored';
  @Output() public cNameChange:EventEmitter<String> = new EventEmitter<String>();
}

@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: `
    <child [(cName)]="pName"></child>
  `
})
export class App {
  pName:string;

  constructor() {
    this.pName = 'InitialName'
  }
}
```

The parent `pData` is two way bound to child `cData` using the simplified syntax `[(cData)]="pData"`. This means that the parent is both providing the `@Input('cData')` to the child *and* listenting to the `cNameChange` event, which *automatically* changes the bound property, in this case `pData`. This is the only really magical part. But it is what is described in Angular docs, so we just accept it to be true.

So when you type into the second child input, it emits the `cDataChange` event and the `pData` gets changed, per Angular specifications. That `pData` is also the input for `cData`, so that `cData` also needs to change to match the `pData` input.

You can confirm that parent is responsible for the `cData` change by commenting out the first and third input of the child, and just adding

```
<li>cName: {{ cName }}</li>
```

> 2. How does changing the child's `cName` property end up changing the parent's `pName` property?

You're not ever really changing it (explicitly) at any point. This is all handled by the two-way binding. If you add something that *does* explicitly change it, say

```
<button (click)="cName = 'hello'">Change</button>
```

or just simply typing in the third input. When you click the button or type, you will see that it *does not* change the parent, but the children see the change because they're getting input from the `cData`. The only way the parent will see the change is `cData` is only if the `cDataChange` event is emitted with the new value.

So what actually changes the parent is the activity discussed in the previous point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was hoping for more than just "trust the magic". For example, my next question will be why the third text input (bound with `[(ngModel)]`) changes the child's property but not the parent's. Looks like the magic isn't working; what do I do about it?

Comment: It's not a "just trust the magic" answer in regards to your concerns. The only magic I mentioned is that from the `[()]` syntax, Angular changes the value for us on input the input side when the change is emitted through `cDataChange`. This is specified in the documentation, and any further elaboration would mean explaining the internal source code, which shouldn't be necessary to address the concerns in your question.

Comment: As for your third concern, that is addressed in the post. The parent `pData` is only undated on `cDataChange` events. The third box never fires that

Comment: Maybe you miss the understanding that `[(cData)]` is just shorthand for `[cData]="" (cDataChange)=""` just like `[(ngModel)]` is shorthand for `[ngModel]="" (ngModelChange)=""`

Comment: So, my second example with `[ngModel]="..." (ngModelChange)="..."` is the same as my third example with `[(ngModel)]="..."`, right? So why do they behave differently (i.e. the second changes the parent value, the third doesn't)?

Comment: It behaves differently because the second explicitly calls `cDataChange`, while the third only changes the `cData` property. This is explained in the update (top of post). Changing the `cData` and emitting the `cDataChange` are two completely different things